# How to calculate the surface temperature of a material when illuminated by laser

Tags: thermodynamics, laser

I'm currently wondering how to calculate the equilibrium surface temperature of a spherical particle when illuminated by the 1 Watt laser.

The particle is in the room temperature with 1 atm air and is being illuminated on one side by the laser. The effect of wind is neglected.

Could you give me some advice where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rough approximation about its surface temperature by assuming it to be a blackbody and then measuring the amount of heat radiated by the body, thereby measuring the radiated flux. Then use Stefan's Law.

Hope this helps.